# Implementation details

Tags: python, class, pandas

I was looking into the source code of the pandas library because I want to learn more about the implementation. A look at the Series class made me ponder a bit. If I hide a lot of details the class is defined like so:

```
class Series(np.ndarray, generic.PandasObject):
    def __new__(cls, data=None, index=None, dtype=None, name=None, copy=False):
        # some checkings
        subarray = _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True)
        return subarray
    def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, dtype=None, name=None, copy=False):
        pass
    # other class methods
def _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype=None, copy=False, raise_cast_failure=False):
    # some more instance checks
    subarr = np.array(arr, dtype=object, copy=copy)
    return subarray
```

That got me all confused because neither has the cls argument been used nor calls to the superclasses have been made. I don't see how this code works. As far as I understand it the Series class should be just a ndarray in disguise, because that's was is returned. Clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 0.12, `Series` is a subclass of `ndarray`, with lots of overriden methods. You are missing:

```
subarr = subarr.view(Series) which makes a ``Series`` a sub-class
```

In any event, the code changed quite a bit, so in 0.13, `Series` is now just like the other pandas objects and a sub-class of `NDFrame`, rather than a subclass of `ndarray`.

See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/release.html#internal-refactoring)